# Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'MyObject'

Tags: typescript

I want to write a web-application on Webstorm with Angular2. I am very new on do this. I am trying the tutorial on the angular website [Angular.IO](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2).

When I try to make a list of Person clickable, it is not working.

```
export class PersonComponent {
 persons = MYPERSONS;
 selectedPersons = Person;

 onSelect(person: Person): void {
  this.selectedPerson = person;   // here is the error on "this.selectedPerson"
 }
}

const MYPERSONS: Person[] = [
 {id:0, firstName: 'First', lastName: 'Firstly', creationData: 1},
 {id:1, firstName: 'Second', lastName: 'Test', creationData:10},
 {id:2, firstName: 'Third', lastName: 'Candidate', creationData:5}
];

export class Person {
 id: number;
 firstName: string;
 lastName: string;
 creationData: any;
}
```

I get the following error:

> Type 'Person' is not assignable to type 'typeof Person'.
>     Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'Person'.

What does it mean? I can't find this error on the internet. It is probably anything what I'm not seeing on the code because of my few experience

Answer (score 77, accepted):

When you write like this:

```
selectedPersons = Person;
```

you're assigning a default value of a class Person **reference** to the variable `selectedPersons`. What you're probably intending to do is to specify that `selectedPersons` class property will hold a  `Person` class instance. You can do it like this:

```
selectedPersons:Person;
```